# Convert column to date with mixed types. "to_datetime" not working

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Here is my data frame:

```
   INV_NUM        LOCATION        CREATED_DATE     DATE_OPENED
      1             North           10/10/2020      10/11/2020
      2             North           10/11/2020      10/11/2020
      3             South           10/12/2020      10/01/2020
      4             West            10/13/2020      WIP
```

I want to create an output that makes a new column called "STATUS". If the "CREATED_DATE" is before "DATE_OPENED" return "Closed", if it is on or after "DATE_OPENED" return "Open", if "DATE_OPENED" is 'WIP' then return "Closed".

Here is the code I wrote to do that:

Define a function:

```
def date_test(row):
    if row['DATE OPENED'] == 'WIP':
        return 'Closed'
    if row['CREATED_DATE'] < row['DATE OPENED']:
        return 'Closed'
    if row['CREATED_DATE'] >= row['DATE OPENED']:
        return 'Open'
    else:
        return 0000
```

Change the type to datetime:

```
df['DATE OPENED'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE OPENED'], errors='ignore')
df['CREATED_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['CREATED_DATE'], errors='raise')
```

Test the function:

```
df['STATUS'] = df.apply(lambda row: date_test(row), axis=1)
```

When I run that code here is the error I get:

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Timestamp' and
> 'str'

I also found that the dtype for column "DATE_OPENED" remained as 'non-null object' after running to_datetime.

I think its the 'WIP' throwing it off but it should ignore that one and continue changing the others and the function looks for the 'WIP' string first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is in this line:

```py
df['DATE OPENED'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE OPENED'], errors='ignore')
```

`errors='ignore'` appears to return the whole series in its original form and thus none of the strings in that column are converted to datetime objects. I recommend using `errors='coerce'` that is going to change your 'WIP' stings into NaT objects and you'll have to update your function to handle that, but something like this should work:

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(
        INV_NUM = [1,2,3,4],
        LOCATION = "North North South West".split(),
        CREATED_DATE = "10/10/2020 10/11/2020 10/12/2020 10/13/2020".split(),
        DATE_OPENED = "10/11/2020 10/11/2020 10/01/2020 WIP".split(),
))

def date_test(row):
    if row['DATE_OPENED'] is pd.NaT:
        return 'Closed'
    if row['CREATED_DATE'] < row['DATE_OPENED']:
        return 'Closed'
    if row['CREATED_DATE'] >= row['DATE_OPENED']:
        return 'Open'
    else:
        return 0000

df['DATE_OPENED'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE_OPENED'], errors='coerce')
df['CREATED_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['CREATED_DATE'], errors='raise')

df['STATUS'] = df.apply(lambda row: date_test(row), axis=1)
```

[step through the code in python tutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import%20pandas%20as%20pd%0A%0A%0Adf%20%3D%20pd.DataFrame%28%0A%20%20%20%20dict%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20INV_NUM%20%3D%20%5B1,2,3,4%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20LOCATION%20%3D%20%22North%20North%20South%20West%22.split%28%29,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20CREATED_DATE%20%3D%20%2210/10/2020%2010/11/2020%2010/12/2020%2010/13/2020%22.split%28%29,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20DATE_OPENED%20%3D%20%2210/11/2020%2010/11/2020%2010/01/2020%20WIP%22.split%28%29,%0A%29%29%0A%0Adef%20date_test%28row%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20row%5B%27DATE_OPENED%27%5D%20is%20pd.NaT%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%27Closed%27%0A%20%20%20%20if%20row%5B%27CREATED_DATE%27%5D%20%3C%20row%5B%27DATE_OPENED%27%5D%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%27Closed%27%0A%20%20%20%20if%20row%5B%27CREATED_DATE%27%5D%20%3E%3D%20row%5B%27DATE_OPENED%27%5D%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%27Open%27%0A%20%20%20%20else%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%200000%0A%0Adf%5B%27DATE_OPENED%27%5D%20%3D%20pd.to_datetime%28df%5B%27DATE_OPENED%27%5D,%20errors%3D%27coerce%27%29%0Adf%5B%27CREATED_DATE%27%5D%20%3D%20pd.to_datetime%28df%5B%27CREATED_DATE%27%5D,%20errors%3D%27raise%27%29%0A%0Adf%5B%27STATUS%27%5D%20%3D%20df.apply%28lambda%20row%3A%20date_test%28row%29,%20axis%3D1%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=8&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=py3anaconda&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

Edit:
If you want to keep `errors='ignore'` and those 'WIP' strings then this should work:

```py
df['DATE_OPENED'] = df['DATE_OPENED'].apply(
    lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, errors='ignore')
)
```

[python tutor link 2](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import%20pandas%20as%20pd%0A%0A%0Adf%20%3D%20pd.DataFrame%28%0A%20%20%20%20dict%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20INV_NUM%20%3D%20%5B1,2,3,4%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20LOCATION%20%3D%20%22North%20North%20South%20West%22.split%28%29,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20CREATED_DATE%20%3D%20%2210/10/2020%2010/11/2020%2010/12/2020%2010/13/2020%22.split%28%29,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20DATE_OPENED%20%3D%20%2210/11/2020%2010/11/2020%2010/01/2020%20WIP%22.split%28%29,%0A%29%29%0A%0Adef%20date_test%28row%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20row%5B%27DATE_OPENED%27%5D%20%3D%3D%20%27WIP%27%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%27Closed%27%0A%20%20%20%20if%20row%5B%27CREATED_DATE%27%5D%20%3C%20row%5B%27DATE_OPENED%27%5D%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%27Closed%27%0A%20%20%20%20if%20row%5B%27CREATED_DATE%27%5D%20%3E%3D%20row%5B%27DATE_OPENED%27%5D%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%27Open%27%0A%20%20%20%20else%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%200000%0A%0Adf%5B%27DATE_OPENED%27%5D%20%3D%20df%5B%27DATE_OPENED%27%5D.apply%28lambda%20x%3A%20pd.to_datetime%28x,%20errors%3D%27ignore%27%29%29%0Adf%5B%27CREATED_DATE%27%5D%20%3D%20pd.to_datetime%28df%5B%27CREATED_DATE%27%5D,%20errors%3D%27raise%27%29%0A%0Adf%5B%27STATUS%27%5D%20%3D%20df.apply%28lambda%20row%3A%20date_test%28row%29,%20axis%3D1%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=8&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=py3anaconda&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the logic. Given the df, convert both columns to_datetime, leaving NaT for invalid dates ('WIP')

```
df['DATE_OPENED'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE_OPENED'], errors='coerce')
df['CREATED_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['CREATED_DATE'], errors='coerce')
```

Now create a column STATUS with 'Closed' as default:

```
df['STATUS'] = 'Closed'
```

Since any comparison to `NaT` will give `False`, you can set 'Open' as

```
df.loc[df['CREATED_DATE'] >= df['DATE_OPENED'], 'STATUS'] = 'Open'
```

giving you

```
df
   INV_NUM LOCATION CREATED_DATE DATE_OPENED  STATUS
0        1    North   2020-10-10  2020-10-11  Closed
1        2    North   2020-10-11  2020-10-11  Open
2        3    South   2020-10-12  2020-10-01  Open
3        4     West   2020-10-13         NaT  Closed
```

Comment: @rujole13: another idea would be to use [isna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) to get a mask where a datetime column is NaT and use it to set the according STATUS entry to, for example, 'undefined'.